# How do I use maths and a 2d graph using random numbers in Java

Tags: java, random, 2d, coordinates

So basically for a school project I have to solve the following problem by writing a Java application.

It is about 3 soldiers: C, H and L. All are plotted on a 2D graph randomly where 0=

The winner will be the last soldier remaining on the battlefield. When a soldier dies, he gets taken off the graph, so his position becomes (-1,-1) besides for C, he stays in the same position even if he is dead. Also, if one soldier kills another, the murderer takes the dead soldier's position on the battlefield (graph), so the coordinates change.

The program needs to print the winner, along when every time a soldier dies (e.g. "C has been killed by H", "H has been killed by L", "L is victorious").

My way of starting this problem has been by creating 2 classes (one for the soldiers and their attributes and the other showing the battlefield). The school recommends we import: 'java.awt.geom.Point2D' for the battlefield and coordinates and 'java.util.Random' to create the random coordinates for putting the soldiers on the field. I'm assuming an algorithm needs to be written to work out which soldier would reach to the other the quickest and which one survives.

However now I am very stuck and have no clue where to go after assigning String names and double values to each soldier variable. Please help!

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and take note of item 3: *"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."* This means, show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us a lot about how you're actually representing the data.

My thinking is you'd have a Battlefield class with dimensions (max_x, max_y), An array of soldiers, and a Display method that draws the battlefield and each soldier's name at the soldier's location on the board (if non-negative).

Soldiers would have a name, and location. The constructor would accept a name and location, which the Battlefield would probably generate (don't want two soldiers on top of each other, etc).

Of course, without knowing how attacks are actually supposed to work, how victory conditions for a battle are resolved, etc, it's hard to offer much else.

Comment: The data doesn't actually need to be represented, it just needs to be present in the code, all the program needs to do is print what I have included in my question. And the part I'm stuck on is working with the numbers and programming them in a way that would print the name of the winner. The winner isn't always necessarily the same since the soldiers are in a random position each time the software is launched.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what all is happening, and that may be your issue as well.

Consider: C is at (5,10), H is at (7,10), L is at (1,1). At this point, we have initialized the "board", but I have no idea what happens next. I have no idea who attacks first, though it seems C would prefer to target H and vice versa, while L would prefer to target C. Beyond this, I really don't know what happens.

Can you work out a couple concrete examples and explain why what you assert happens should?